# Spark Gaussian Mixture Data Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gaussian, rdd

What is the data format that the Gaussian Mixture Model in spark needs ? Should the data be in a vector format , RDD or which type?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example: [Gaussian Mixture](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#gaussian-mixture).

It takes a `RDD[Vector]` as an input.